# Can a table used in place of option for a datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am fetching shifts from a server in my controller.But the status names are very long texts so when displayed my options looks really ugly. Is there any better way to use instead  of option?

```
<input class="form-control" id="shiftt" ng-model="body.DispatchStatus" list= "allShifts" />
<datalist id="allShifts">
  <option ng-repeat="shift in shifts" value="{{shift.statusName}}">{{shift.statusName}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: No. `datalist` can only contain `option` elements, and `option` can only contain text nodes.

Comment: thanks, I'll switch to modal and a button then :)